# Standardscaler v Min Max. Standardscaler is not working for ANN but MInMax does

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, normalization

I have a dataset with multiple features and a target. I am using ANN to predict. When I scale the features using `MInMax`, everything works fine and during the compile and fix I get good loss and accuracy.
HOWEVER, when I use `StandardScaler()`. The prediction is off and then I noticed during the Compile/fit I get `acc:0.00000` through out the whole epoch.
Just wondering why. I thought I can use any (specially `StandardScaler`).
Any suggestion?
Thank you

```
Epoch 100/100
404/404 [==============================] - 0s 17us/step - loss: 0.2729 - acc: 0.0000e+00
```

(when I use StandardScaler() !!!)

here is the code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')
#sns.pairplot(dataset)

X=dataset.iloc[:,0:13]
y=dataset.iloc[:,13].values
#StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc2= StandardScaler()
X= sc2.fit_transform(X)
y= y.reshape(-1,1)
y=sc2.fit_transform(y)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(Dense(units=13, input_dim=13))
regressor.add(Dense(units=1))
regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error',  metrics=['accuracy'])
regressor.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Hi yaho. I just updated it with the code.  Thanks